# android youtube app list fadeout edge

Tags: android, listview, youtube, fade

enter the youtube app -> click on browse, there would be a category list, all the edges of which fades out at both ends, this looks very nice and silky, any one has an idea how to achieve that? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought this was the default. You can control this with [fadingEdge](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3afadingEdge) in xml:

```
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
```

or in Java:

```
listView.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```

For bonus points you can increase the length of the fading edge using:

```
android:fadingEdgeLength="50dp"
```

I don't think there is a Java equivalent for that.

**Edit** - for the divider you can use a gradient [shape drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) to get that effect. For example, in `res/drawable/divider.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#00000000"
        android:centerColor="#808080"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="0"/>
</shape>
```

and then set it with `android:divider="@drawable/divider"` and possibly `android:dividerHeight="1dp"` on your `ListView`.

Comment: Sorry, I should be more specific. I am not talking about that fadeout. I am talking about the lines between list item, the default listView just offers a thin white line, but youtube app actually has a line that is highlighted in the center, and fades out towards both ends(left&right), how's that accomplished?

Comment: by the way, I tried android:fadingEdge="horizontal", but it doesn't work.

Comment: It's only going to work if your content scrolls horizontally.

Comment: Sorry for being such a newbie, but after I followed that, now there are no divider any more, can you please help me fix this, thanks

Comment: Did you try setting the divider height as well?

Comment: set it to 1dip and solved, thanks for all the help, you guys are amazing